# how to use overpass to get all street in a city

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

1. I am trying to get a polygon of a road using the nodes returned by overpass-api.
   For example, these code lines get all ways having the name `New York`

```
import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()
result = api.query("""way["name"="New York"];out;""")
```

`result.ways` outputs :

```
 [<overpy.Way id=13299262 nodes=[122693667, 122693669]>
 <overpy.Way id=16853691 nodes=[174614245, 1474795638, 174617781, 174614749]>,
...
]
```

Each way has multiple nodes. How to make a polygon of the road using those nodes, and then test if a specific gps coordinate, for example (gps=(lat=4.78, long=6.67)), lies on that road (polygon) ? 
How could I handle the case where there are only two nodes available ?

2. My second question is, how to query lat and long coordinates of each node  ? I have tried it with:

```
for way in result.ways:
    for node in way.nodes:
        print(node.lon, node.lat)
```

But I get the error, `DataIncomplete: ('Data incomplete try to improve the query to resolve the missing data', 'Resolve missing nodes is disabled')`. 
When I add this line: `nodes = way.get_nodes(resolve_missing=True)` as mentioned in [the overpy documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-overpy/downloads/pdf/latest/) , I get nothing as output.

Any hints will be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to query all roads around `lat=4.78, long=6.67` (within a radius) and find the closest road to the point, instead of that 'brute force'-like approach ?